# Unable to fetch individual values from firebase data using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am unable display each data received from firebase snapshot, even when I run an forEach or for loop on the returned array that too doesn't works

I have created an function to fetch all entries from firebase, push the snapshot data into an array and then return that array. I am now not able to display the values from the returned array, I tried with forEach and for loop, none of them and working on it, even it is not showing the length of array properly.

Function which fetches all data from firebase this is returning expected data properly

```
function fetchAllEntries(firebaseDB) {
  // Create a reference to the database.
  const fetchedData = database.ref(firebaseDB);

  // Create an array to store the results.
  let results = [];

  // Use the on() method to listen for changes to the query results.
  fetchedData.on("value", (snapshot) => {
    // Get the data from the snapshot.
    const data = snapshot.val();
    results.push(data);
  });
  // Return the results array.
  return results;
}
```

Screenshot of how array is displayed in console log for reference -
[Array Reference Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wDSj.png)

Not working implementation - 1

```
fetchedData.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
  });
```

Not working implementation - 2

```
console.log(fetchedData[0]);
```

All this implementation is done with Vanilla JS

If anyone could help with how can I loop through results array and display each value would be really helpful.

Comment: `.on('value')` subscribes a listener that fires every time there's an update. It looks more like you just want to use `.get()`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once. In either case though, fetching data is asynchronous and needs to be handled as such